# Can I say that a Θ(n^3/2)-time algorithm is asymptotically slower than an Θ(n log n)-time algorithm?

Tags: asymptotic-complexity, big-o

I analyzed an algorithm and for running time I got Θ(n<sup>3/2</sup>). Now I want to compare it with Θ(n log n) to see if it is asymptotically faster or slower, for that I did this:

> Θ(n<sup>3/2</sup>) = Θ(n · n<sup>1/2</sup>)

If we compare them we will see that we need to compare the n<sup>1/2</sup> and log n.  I checked the growth of both and I found that for larger numbers the growth of n<sup>1/2</sup> is more than log n. Can I say that n<sup>3/2</sup> is **asymptotically** slower than log n?

Comment: At the very end of the question, shouldn't it be nlogn instead of logn?

Comment: Also, shouldn't the title say "asymptotically faster"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. For any ε > 0, log n = o(n<sup>ε</sup>) (that's little-o, by the way), so the log function grows asymptotically slower than any positive power of n. Therefore, n log n grows asymptotically slower than n<sup>3/2</sup>.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for answering:) just another question: if I have theta(n) can I say it is asymptotically faster that theta(nlogn)? (I ask  this because theta(n) is not n^ε bigger than theta( nlogn) )

Answer (score 2):

You can prove it yourself by applying [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule):

[image: sketch]

[This](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=for%20n%20to%20inf%20nlog(n)%2Fn%5E(3%2F2)) might also help.

Answer (score 1):

If you plot the two, you see that x^(3/2) (black on plot( grows faster than x*log(x) (red on plot): 
http://fooplot.com/#W3sidHlwZSI6MCwiZXEiOiJ4XigzLzIpIiwiY29sb3IiOiIjMDAwMDAwIn0seyJ0eXBlIjoyLCJlcXgiOiIxNipzaW4ocyleMyIsImVxeSI6IjEzKmNvcyhzKS02KmNvcygyKnMpLTIqY29zKDMqcyktY29zKDQqcykiLCJjb2xvciI6IiNGRjAwMDAiLCJzbWluIjoiLXBpIiwic21heCI6InBpIiwic3N0ZXAiOiIuMDEifSx7InR5cGUiOjAsImVxIjoieCpsb2coeCkiLCJjb2xvciI6IiNCRjFCMUIifSx7InR5cGUiOjEwMDAsIndpbmRvdyI6WyItMjcuNDI0Mjk1Mzg0NjE1MzczIiwiMzguMTExNzA0NjE1Mzg0NTk2IiwiLTcuODczNTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5IiwiMzIuNDU2MjQ2MTUzODQ2MTQiXX1d